# Getting error java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found while using softhsm as hsm

Tags: keytool, softhsm, sunpkcs11

I am using command line tool "keytool" to create a key pair in softhsm.
I have added security.provider in java.security.

```
# List of providers and their preference orders (see above):
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.3=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.4=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.5=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.6=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider 
security.provider.7=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.8=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI 
security.provider.9=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
security.provider.10=sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI 
security.provider.11=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11
${java.home}/lib/security/pkcs11.cfg
```

and My pkcs11.cfg looks like

```
name = SoftHSM v2  
library = C:/SoftHSM2/lib/softhsm2-x64.dll 
slot = 0
```

While running 
    keytool.exe -keystore NONE -storetype PKCS11 -list

I am getting the error

```
keytool error: java.security.KeyStoreException: PKCS11 not found.
```

Can you please help?